# Couldn't find Habit with 'id'=id < ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in HabitsController#showのエラー

Tags: ruby-on-rails

indexから詳細画面のshowに飛ぶ際、habits/1のようなidを取得したURLにしたいのですが、
URLがhabits/idのようになります。どこに間違いがあるのかわからずつまづいております。
ペーペーな質問で、申し訳ございませんが、助けて頂けると幸甚です！

こちらがindex.htmlです

```
<% @habits.each do |hb| %>
<table class="habit_table">
<tr>
    <td><%= link_to hb.routine, habit_path(:id) %></td>
    <td>継続記録<%= hb.days %>日</td>
    <td><%= link_to "Edit", edit_habit_path(:id) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to "Delete", habit_path(:id), method: :delete, data: {  confirm: "Are You Sure to Delete ?"} %></td>
</tr>
```

habits_controller

```
    class HabitsController < ApplicationController

 before_action :find_by_id, only:[:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

def index
@habits = Habit.all
end

def show
end

private

def find_by_id
@habit = Habit.find(params[:id])
end

def habit_params
params.require(:habit).permit!
end

end
```

show.html

```
<h2><%= @habit.routine %></h2>

<table>
<tr>
<td>継続記録<%= @habit.days %>日</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

rooting

```
root 'habits#index'
resources :habits
```

Answer (score 1):

一度、Railsガイドに目を通されることをお勧めします。

[1.2 コードからパスやURLを生成する](http://railsguides.jp/routing.html#%E3%82%B3%E3%83%BC%E3%83%89%E3%81%8B%E3%82%89%E3%83%91%E3%82%B9%E3%82%84url%E3%82%92%E7%94%9F%E6%88%90%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B)

path に渡すのは、インスタンスですね。

```
<td><%= link_to hb.routine, habit_path(hb) %></td>
```

Comment: なるほど！ありがとうございます！なんとなくでやってて理解してませんでした。無事動きました！感謝感激です！